# Can a Pentagram destroy experience orbs while a Vacuum is in effect?

Tags: vampire-survivors

[The Vacuum](https://vampire-survivors.fandom.com/wiki/Vacuum) is a pickup item that pulls all experience gems lying on the ground towards the player. [The Pentagram](https://vampire-survivors.fandom.com/wiki/Pentagram) has a chance of destroying any items on screen when activated.

If the Pentagram activates while a Vacuum is in effect, will the Pentagram destroy the attracted experience gems before they reach the player?